# Trouble understanding priors

Tags: prior

The following comes from a book called [Bayesian Statistics by Ben Lambert](https://amzn.to/4aQTUL3):

> Assuming the following model for $r$ disease-positive people out of $n$ people:
> $$Pr(Z=r, \theta) = {n\choose r}\theta^r(1-\theta)^{n-r}.$$
> The probability that one disease-positive is $\theta$ and the probability that two randomly chosen individuals both have the disease is $\theta^2$.

I fully understand everything thus far. Then this is said

> If we assume a flat prior for $\theta$, then this implies the decreasing prior for $\theta^2$ shown by the red line

[image]

I am flummoxed. I don't even know where to begin unpacking this. Could someone lend me a hand with understanding this?

Comment: the meat of the matter is a fact of probability, not specifically Bayes, namely the effect of transformations on the density function; see e.g. https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/22/22.2

Comment: $P(X^2\le y)=P(X\le \sqrt{y})=\sqrt{y}$ with derivative (i.e. density) $\dfrac1{2\sqrt{y}}$ which looks like the red curve

Comment: Not surprisingly, Gelman has had much to say about priors, e.g., "The Bayesian prior distribution corresponds to the frequentist sample space: it’s the set of problems for which a particular statistical model or procedure will be applied," and many more thoughts have been posted to his blog. https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2024/01/08/bayesians-are-frequentists-2/

Comment: @Henry Your comment made it click :) Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This picture [from Lambert](https://amzn.to/4aQTUL3) is admittedly bad and confusing.

[image]

It represents on the *same* graph three probability densities for three *different* random variables,
$$\theta\,,\quad\zeta=\theta^2\,,\text{ and }\xi=\theta^{10}$$
This means that the value $0.4$ on the first axis leads to the density at $\theta=0.4$ for the black flat line *and* to the density at $\zeta=0,4$, i.e. at $\theta=\sqrt{0.4}$, for the red curve *and* to the density at $\xi=0.4$, i.e. $\theta={0.4}^{1/10}$ for the black dashed curve. **There is no reason to plot them together!**

The three curves
$$f_1(\theta)=\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(\theta)\,,\quad
f_2(\zeta)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\xi}}\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(\zeta)\,,\quad
f_3(\xi)=\frac{\xi^{-9/10}}{10}\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(\xi)$$
obtained by [the change of variable formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function) should have instead been plotted on different graphs.